# How to parse AREAS() using poi formula parser

Tags: java, function, apache-poi

How to parse the AREAS(B5:B6, C5:C8) Function using APACHE POI formula parser.

Comment: Did you try the [regular POI Formula Evaluation code](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)? If so, what did it give? If not, what happens if you try?

Comment: Regular formula parser is designed to handle only either = Areas((A5)) Or = Sum(Sum(1,6)). If I try to parse areas((A5:A6, D5:D6)) Only formula parser exception is thrown . Exception : Expected ')' but found ','.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Apache POI Functions Metadata](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/resources/main/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/function/functionMetadata.txt) we see that the `AREAS` function has ID 75.

Next, we look in the [Formula Functions implementation lookup list](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.java) and see that there's no entry in there for ID 75. That tells us that there's currently no Apache POI implementation of the AREAS function

Therefore, what you'll need to do is write a bit of code to implement the function, then please [submit it back to the project](http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html)!

You'll want to have a look at the [Formula Evaluations Developer Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html) on the website, and [this talk from ApacheCon](http://people.apache.org/~yegor/apachecon_us2010/Evaluation_Of_Excel_Formulas_In_POI.pptx) which goes over how formula evaluation in Excel works, and how to implement a new function in POI.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.I will subscribe to the mailing list and try to develop the function.

Comment: I wrote the functionality for the areas function but i don't know how to parse the double braces using formula parser [=AREAS((B4:B7,D5:D8)) ].

Comment: Best ask on the [POI dev list](http://poi.apache.org/mailinglists.html). I've only ever written simple functions, but there ought to be other people there who do know how!